# why we use two conditions in head!=nullptr && head->next != nullptr in floyd cycle detection algorithm?

Tags: c++, while-loop, linked-list, null-pointer, negation

i want to know that why we use two conditions
i am confused.. while head and head->next are not equal to null which means head and head's next will point to null ho is that possible

```
int detectCycle(Node *& head)
{
   Node * fast = head;
   Node * slow = head;
   while(fast!=nullptr && fast->next!=nullptr)   // i am confused in these two conditions
   {
     slow = slow->next;
     fast = fast->next->next;
     if(fast == slow)
        return 1;
   }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think "head and head's next will point to null" if they are **not equal** to `nullptr`?

Comment: You need to check that `fast` is not `nullptr` before you try to dereference it to get to `fast->next`.

Comment: I'm not following what it is that's confusing you.  Are you asking about the meaning of `!=nullptr`?  Are you asking about why there are two tests instead of just one?  Something else?

Comment: If you just did `if (fast->next)` and `fast` was `nullptr`, what would you expect to happen?   (The answer is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)).

Comment: `return 1;` - don't do that in a function returning `bool`. `return true;` instead. It does the same thing, but don't be weird when writing code - you have to read it again in the future.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i am asking whether head and head->next cant point to null ? if yes how?

Comment: "i am asking whether head and head->next cant point to null ?" - How can we know? You didn't post enough code. We can't see how your function is called. Someone could easily be calling it with `nullptr` as an argument.

Comment: `head` and `head->next` (or `fast` and `fast->next`) cannot *both* be null at the same time, because if `head` is null then `head->next` is undefined.  But I see no reason why one or the other couldn't be null.  If you think you see such a reason then maybe it would help to try to explain that to us.  Or even to your rubber duck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while head and head->next are not equal to null which means head and head's next will point to null ho is that possible

From the code presented, I guess you mean `fast` where you wrote `head`.

If `fast` is null then `fast!=nullptr` evaluates to false.  In that case it would produce undefined behavior to evaluate `fast->next`, but that is not an issue because the `&&` operator has short-circuiting behavior.  That is, if the left operand of an `&&` operator evaluates to false, then the right operand is not evaluated.

Thus the `while` condition is safe to evaluate, and it evaluates to true if and only if neither `fast` nor `fast->next` is a null pointer.

Supposing that `head` is a pointer to the head node of a linked list, the code seems to assume that the last node can be recognized by having a `next` pointer whose value is null.  This is a very common paradigm, so it is absolutely reasonable to think that as the `fast` pointer is advanced through the list (two links at a time), it will eventually become the case that either it or its successor will be the last node, and therefore have a null `next` pointer.

If that happens, then the list is proven not to loop.  If the list *does* loop, however, then it will eventually be the case that `slow`, which advances only one link at a time instead of two, will point to the same node that `fast` does.  When that is detected, the list is known to loop.

Answer (score 1):

This condition

```
while(fast!=nullptr && fast->next!=nullptr)
```

means that the current pointer `fast` and its data member `next` that is a pointer to the next node are not null pointers. If so you may write

```
 fast = fast->next->next;
```

And the function should be declared like

```
bool detectCycle(Node *& head)
^^^^
```